# if i run the query i am not getting the output (it's showing null values )

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    [BILLDATE]as BILLDATE
    ,PROPERTYCODE   
    ,[RESTUARANTNAME] as RESTUARANTNAME
    ,rt.FOODREVENUE
    ,rt.LIQUORREVENUE
    ,rt.TOBACCOREVENUE
    ,rt.SOFTDRINKSREVENUE
    ,rt.OTHERREVENUE
    ,rt.FOODCOVERS
    ,rt.LIQUORCOVERS
    ,rt.SOFTDRINKSCOVERS
    ,rt.TOBACCOCOVERS
    ,rt.OTHERCOVERS
from CoversToday t
cross apply     
    (select
        SUM([FOODREVENUE])as FOODREVENUE
      ,SUM([LIQUORREVENUE])as LIQUORREVENUE
      ,SUM([SOFTDRINKSREVENUE])as SOFTDRINKSREVENUE
      ,SUM([TOBACCOREVENUE])as TOBACCOREVENUE
      ,SUM([OTHERREVENUE])as OTHERREVENUE
      ,SUM([FOODCOVERS])as FOODCOVERS
      ,SUM([LIQUORCOVERS])as LIQUORCOVERS
      ,SUM([SOFTDRINKSCOVERS])as SOFTDRINKSCOVERS
      ,SUM([TOBACCOCOVERS])as TOBACCOCOVERS
      ,SUM([OTHERCOVERS])as OTHERCOVERS
     from CoversToday
     where 
     PROPERTYcode = t.PROPERTYcode and [RESTUARANTNAME]=t.[RESTUARANTNAME] and
     [BILLDATE] BETWEEN dateadd(year, datediff(MONTH, 0,t.[BILLDATE]),0) -- start of month
AND t.[BILLDATE] 
    ) as rt
```

Comment: This part is working fine. but i am not getting the output

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add details - it's unreadable in the comments.

Comment: Sure..  In that query (all SUM function working fine) but i am not getting the output . it's showing null values     please help me

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 1):

Start of month is `dateadd(MONTH, datediff(MONTH, 0, t.[BILLDATE]), 0)` not `dateadd(year,...`

Start of year is `dateadd(YEAR, datediff(YEAR, 0, t.[BILLDATE]), 0)`

Answer (score 0):

```
dateadd(year, datediff(MONTH, 0,t.[BILLDATE]),0)
```

**that is your Mistak**.

See [DateDiff](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms189794.aspx)

**Update :**

correcting the mistake :

```
DateAdd(MONTH, DateDiff(MONTH, 0, T.[BILLDATE]), 0)
```

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

declare @fymonth int = 4; -- first month of FY.

SELECT DISTINCT
     BILLDATE 
    ,PROPERTYCODE 
    ,FOODREVENUE AS TODAY_FOODREVENUE
    ,rt.FOODREVENUE_MTOD
    ,rt.FOODREVENUE_YTOD
    ,LIQUORREVENUE AS TODAY_LIQUORREVENUE
    ,rt.LIQUORREVENUE_MTOD
    ,rt.LIQUORREVENUE_YTOD
    ,TOBACCOREVENUE AS TODAY_TOBACCOREVENUE
    ,rt.TOBACCOREVENUE_MTOD
    ,rt.TOBACCOREVENUE_YTOD
    ,SOFTDRINKSREVENUE AS TODAY_SOFTDRINKSREVENUE
    ,rt.SOFTDRINKSREVENUE_MTOD
    ,rt.SOFTDRINKSREVENUE_YTOD
    ,OTHERREVENUE AS TODAY_OTHERREVENUE
    ,rt.OTHERREVENUE_MTOD
    ,rt.OTHERREVENUE_YTOD
    ,FOODCOVERS AS TODAY_FOODCOVERS
    ,rt.FOODCOVERS_MTOD
    ,rt.FOODCOVERS_YTOD
    ,LIQUORCOVERS AS TODAY_LIQUORCOVERS
    ,rt.LIQUORCOVERS_MTOD
    ,rt.LIQUORCOVERS_YTOD
    ,SOFTDRINKSCOVERS AS TODAY_SOFTDRINKSCOVERS
    ,rt.SOFTDRINKSCOVERS_MTOD
    ,rt.SOFTDRINKSCOVERS_YTOD
    ,TOBACCOCOVERS AS TODAY_TOBACCOCOVERS
    ,rt.TOBACCOCOVERS_MTOD
    ,rt.TOBACCOCOVERS_YTOD
    ,OTHERCOVERS AS TODAY_OTHERCOVERS
    ,rt.OTHERCOVERS_MTOD
    ,rt.OTHERCOVERS_YTOD

FROM CoversToday t
CROSS APPLY
    (SELECT

```
----FOODREVENUE

    SUM(t2.Foodrevenue) AS  FOODREVENUE_YTOD

     ,SUM(CASE WHEN t2.BILLDATE BETWEEN 
            -- start of month for t.BILLDATE
        dateadd(MONTH, datediff(MONTH, 0, t3.BILLDATE), 0)
        AND t3.BILLDATE
     THEN t2.Foodrevenue END) AS FOODREVENUE_MTOD

 ----LIQUORREVENUE

 ,SUM(t2.LIQUORREVENUE) AS  LIQUORREVENUE_YTOD

     ,SUM(CASE WHEN t2.BILLDATE BETWEEN 
            -- start of month for t.BILLDATE
        dateadd(MONTH, datediff(MONTH, 0, t3.BILLDATE), 0)
        AND t3.BILLDATE
     THEN t2.LIQUORREVENUE END) AS LIQUORREVENUE_MTOD    

 ----TOBACCOREVENUE  

 ,SUM(t2.TOBACCOREVENUE) AS  TOBACCOREVENUE_YTOD

     ,SUM(CASE WHEN t2.BILLDATE BETWEEN 
            -- start of month for t.BILLDATE
        dateadd(MONTH, datediff(MONTH, 0, t3.BILLDATE), 0)
        AND t3.BILLDATE
     THEN t2.TOBACCOREVENUE END) AS TOBACCOREVENUE_MTOD    

 ----SOFTDRINKSREVENUE     


 ,SUM(t2.SOFTDRINKSREVENUE) AS  SOFTDRINKSREVENUE_YTOD

     ,SUM(CASE WHEN t2.BILLDATE BETWEEN 
            -- start of month for t.BILLDATE
        dateadd(MONTH, datediff(MONTH, 0, t3.BILLDATE), 0)
        AND t3.BILLDATE
     THEN t2.SOFTDRINKSREVENUE END) AS SOFTDRINKSREVENUE_MTOD    

 ----OTHERREVENUE
    ,SUM(t2.OTHERREVENUE) AS  OTHERREVENUE_YTOD

     ,SUM(CASE WHEN t2.BILLDATE BETWEEN 
            -- start of month for t.BILLDATE
        dateadd(MONTH, datediff(MONTH, 0, t3.BILLDATE), 0)
        AND t3.BILLDATE
     THEN t2.OTHERREVENUE END) AS OTHERREVENUE_MTOD    

 ----FOODCOVERS   

    ,SUM(t2.FOODCOVERS) AS  FOODCOVERS_YTOD

     ,SUM(CASE WHEN t2.BILLDATE BETWEEN 
            -- start of month for t.BILLDATE
        dateadd(MONTH, datediff(MONTH, 0, t3.BILLDATE), 0)
        AND t3.BILLDATE
     THEN t2.FOODCOVERS END) AS FOODCOVERS_MTOD    

 ----  LIQUORCOVERS 

    ,SUM(t2.LIQUORCOVERS) AS  LIQUORCOVERS_YTOD

     ,SUM(CASE WHEN t2.BILLDATE BETWEEN 
            -- start of month for t.BILLDATE
        dateadd(MONTH, datediff(MONTH, 0, t3.BILLDATE), 0)
        AND t3.BILLDATE
     THEN t2.LIQUORCOVERS END) AS LIQUORCOVERS_MTOD    

 ----  SOFTDRINKSCOVERS

  ,SUM(t2.SOFTDRINKSCOVERS) AS  SOFTDRINKSCOVERS_YTOD

     ,SUM(CASE WHEN t2.BILLDATE BETWEEN 
            -- start of month for t.BILLDATE
        dateadd(MONTH, datediff(MONTH, 0, t3.BILLDATE), 0)
        AND t3.BILLDATE
     THEN t2.SOFTDRINKSCOVERS END) AS SOFTDRINKSCOVERS_MTOD 


    ----  TOBACCOCOVERS

  ,SUM(t2.TOBACCOCOVERS) AS  TOBACCOCOVERS_YTOD

     ,SUM(CASE WHEN t2.BILLDATE BETWEEN 
            -- start of month for t.BILLDATE
        dateadd(MONTH, datediff(MONTH, 0, t3.BILLDATE), 0)
        AND t3.BILLDATE
     THEN t2.TOBACCOCOVERS END) AS TOBACCOCOVERS_MTOD    


       ----  OTHERCOVERS

  ,SUM(t2.OTHERCOVERS) AS  OTHERCOVERS_YTOD

     ,SUM(CASE WHEN t2.BILLDATE BETWEEN 
            -- start of month for t.BILLDATE
        dateadd(MONTH, datediff(MONTH, 0, t3.BILLDATE), 0)
        AND t3.BILLDATE
     THEN t2.OTHERCOVERS END) AS OTHERCOVERS_MTOD   

 from CoversToday t2
 JOIN CoversToday t3 ON t3.CoversTodayid = t.CoversTodayid -- change as needed to get 1 to 1 JOIN
 where 
 t2.PROPERTYCODE = t.PROPERTYCODE and
 t2.BILLDATE BETWEEN 
            -- FY start for t.BILLDATE
            dateadd(MONTH,
              @fymonth - CASE WHEN month(t.BILLDATE) >= @fymonth THEN 1 ELSE 13 END,
              dateadd(YEAR, datediff(YEAR, 0, t.BILLDATE), 0))
            AND t.BILLDATE 
) as rt

ORDER BY BILLDATE
```